# Kibana visualize query without the dashboard time

Tags: kibana

Is there any way in Kibana to omit the dashboard time from a particular query? The example use case:

I track open sessions, and want to see how many are currently open. The sessions like all the objects I log are imported against their create date. But they also have an expired date.

I want to ignore the creation date and just show sessions that have not expired yet.

I've got the query part like this one from ES:

```
GET /dev/authority/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "_type": "authority"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "_issuedTo.userType": "customer"
            }
          },

          {
            "range": {
              "expires": {
                "gt": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the dashboard is acting like a "between" filter, so it only gets sessions that were created after the dashboard start time. I want to ignore this value and get all matches regardless of create time, can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. 
The time filter applies to all the widgets in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you create index pattern you can specify any date field as Timed-field:

[image]

And from right up corner you can change time interval for time series data:

[image]

Click it and choose whatever you want.